# How to disable flow around elements in table (CSS)

Tags: css, css-tables

I've got products in table. Each have title, price and thumbnail. If thumnails are different, the price element flow around and sometimes it is on top, sometimes on bottom.
I would like to set it is always on top right of the table.

[image]

On picture I marked green, which is ok and red how to change.

Comment: And what did you tried.. first show us the code then we can help is issue is coming..we can't give you ready made code..thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when the product image is narrow enough to fit on one line, it's floating in beside the red label. To fix, add `clear:left` to the product image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the thumbnail and price div to 'float:left' and both div should be given width in '%'. For example,

```
.thumbnail{
   width:75%;
   float:left;
 }

.price{
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
 }
```

Comment: well, sorry to say but don't you think we should use clear:both after using float:left rather then using fix width in %??

Comment: If you do not use fixed width in % both divs will take 100% width and will be one div below another div rather than side by side, even if you use clear:both

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each of your catalog pictures has **a different width**. You need to set either the Cell width (recommended) or the image width, so that all elements will flow the same way in yout HTML page. For instance, if your widest image is 150 pixels wide and your entire cell calculates to 300 pixels, each cell should have a `width:300px;` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

On the `<td>` that contains the article name add a class "whatYouWant"

```
.whatYouWant{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```